# How do I connect to ms access database using sql management tool or any other tool?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2000

I am new to ms access database and I am using ms access 2000.

From the insert query menu from ms access, I cannot directly use sql queries command

**e.g** `select * from table;`

I have microsoft sql database management tool but not sure how to connect directly to ms access to query ms access database tables.

Anyone has any idea how to to that? Any sql tool software recommendation that can directly access ms access database table using sql queries command will also help.

Comment: i think i found one such tool,testing it out,if anyone has any better recommendation tool that most software engineer use,please advise thanks                                                https://razorsql.com/features/access_editor.html

Comment: You can switch queries to SQL view in Access.

Comment: The most easy and best tool is access. As pointed out, you can certainly fire up the query builder and flip into sql mode in which you type in the query. You can also hit ctrl-g and in the debug window also type in sql like: currentdb.Execute "your sql goes here". So like the old FoxPro dot prompt, you can type commands at the access command prompt (debug window), but in actual use + practice, the query builder is the way to go. Let access build your sql - but if  you want to tweak or type in sql directly, there is always sql view available from the query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use MS Access 2000 ? this is 2018 haha
Well if you're as unlucky as I am and your company have old databases and you're stuck with that there are other ways, I'm using MS Access 2003 to open those databases and I use Queries to execute SQL Code, I have MS Access in frensh so here is a screen shot to help
[image: Queries in MS Access 2003]

You only have to create a new query or edit an old one, then siwtch to SQL mode like this:
[image: Switch to SQL Mode]

I'm not sure but I guess you can use the same for MS Access 2000, if you want to use SQL Server you'll have to import data so you'll be no longer working on MS Access !!